# Partial module mock function created using Jest is not called by function under test

Tags: jestjs

(Based on the examples kindly provided already [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/master/examples/module-mock).)
For the module below,

```js
    // fruit.js
    export const apple = 'apple';
    
    export const strawberry = () => 'strawberry';
    
    export default () => `banana and ${strawberry()} `;
```

I would like to write a test that will verify that the ***default*** exported function correctly invokes the function ***strawberry***.
To achieve this I attempted the following test,

```js
    // partial_mock.js
    import defaultExport, { strawberry } from '../fruit';
    
    jest.mock('../fruit', () => {
      const originalModule = require.requireActual('../fruit');
      const mockedModule = jest.genMockFromModule('../fruit');
    
      // Mock the exported 'strawberry' function.
      return Object.assign({}, mockedModule, originalModule, {
        strawberry: jest.fn(() => 'mocked strawberry'),
      });
    });
    
    it('does a partial mock', () => {
      expect(strawberry()).toBe('mocked strawberry');
    
      const defaultExportResult = defaultExport();
      expect(defaultExportResult).toBe('banana and mocked strawberry');
    });
```

However the mocked function is not called, instead, the actual function gets called.

```bash
     × does a partial mock (21ms)
    
      ● does a partial mock
    
        expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality
    
        Expected: "banana and mocked strawberry"
        Received: "banana and strawberry "
```

Is this expected?

Is my test valid? Have I missed anything in my test?

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that by the time Jest imports `fruit.js` to generate a mock from it, the anonymous function in your default export has already grabbed a reference to the actual `strawberry` in its closure.

So all Jest is doing is mocking `strawberry` for any other modules that import it later on, e.g. your test suite.

This article explains some ways to work around this: https://medium.com/@qjli/how-to-mock-specific-module-function-in-jest-715e39a391f4

My suggestion is to consider refactoring your logic before employing any workarounds:

- Do some functions in `fruit.js` serve as implementation detail or used to factor out logic? Maybe you can treat them like private class methods and test them through `defaultExport` itself.
- If their logic is so independent that it needs to be mocked out between tests, maybe the functions should reside in separate modules?