# Mock all except one function in a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, mocking

I am testing `fileA.js`, which requires `fileB.js`

In `fileA.test.js`, I wish to mock all methods from `fileB.js` except one.

In `fileA.test.js` I have:

```
const common = require("../src/fileB");
jest.mock("../src/fileB");
```

There is one method I do not wish to be mocked. Is this sort of thing possible in nodeJS?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Partial module mock function created using Jest is not called by function under test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52722751/partial-module-mock-function-created-using-jest-is-not-called-by-function-under)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `jest.mock` and [jest.requireActual(moduleName)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestrequireactualmodulename) to partial mock the methods/functions of a module.

For example:

`a.js`:

```js
const b = require('./b');

exports.main = function main() {
  console.log(b.method1());
  console.log(b.method2());
  console.log(b.method3());
};
```

`b.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  method1: function() {
    return 'method 1';
  },

  method2: function() {
    return 'method 2';
  },

  method3: function() {
    return 'method 3';
  }
};
```

Now, we will mock all methods of `b.js` except `method3`.

`a.spec.js`:

```js
jest.mock('./b', () => {
  const originalB = jest.requireActual('./b');
  const partialMockedB = Object.keys(originalB).reduce((pre, methodName) => {
    pre[methodName] = jest.fn();
    return pre;
  }, {});
  return {
    ...partialMockedB,
    method3: originalB.method3 // mock all methods of b except method3
  };
});

const { main } = require('./a');
const b = require('./b');

describe('main', () => {
  test('should correct', () => {
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    b.method1.mockReturnValueOnce('mocked method 1');
    b.method2.mockReturnValueOnce('mocked method 2');
    main();
    expect(logSpy.mock.calls[0]).toEqual(['mocked method 1']);
    expect(logSpy.mock.calls[1]).toEqual(['mocked method 2']);
    expect(logSpy.mock.calls[2]).toEqual(['method 3']);
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/58561765/a.spec.js
  main
    ✓ should correct (18ms)

  console.log node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:860
    mocked method 1

  console.log node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:860
    mocked method 2

  console.log node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:860
    method 3

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.65s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/58561765

Comment: you just ended a 2 hour search... cheers!

Comment: couldn't make it work for ES6, where we use "import"s instead of "require"s. Perhaps I did something wrong. Methods of the mocked library all became undefined.

Comment: @schlingel you could try setting `__esModule: true,` https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestrequireactualmodulename